# How to Calculate Data of Previous Month using php variable with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

[If user select the **Month** *november* then it will calculate the data of 
**October** that means **previous month** of **selecting month** by user. I have a column **monthof** in my db billifno table.
$sqll = "SELECT  `client`.`clientId` ,  `billId` ,  `monthOf` ,  `yearOf` , (`arrear` +  `monthlyBill`)AS  'billamount' FROM  `billifno` 
JOIN  `client` ON  `billifno`.`clientID` =  `client`.`clientID` WHERE `monthOf`='".[$_POST["monthOf-1"]]."' AND `billifno`.`clientID`='".$_POST["clientID"]."'";](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UCur.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, cant say you do a lot to be helped here, 1st of all, please get familiar with prepared statements. they will make your code much more support friendly
https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp
. Second, $_POST["monthOf-1"] means you have a field with the name monthOf-1. I assume that is not the case. i assume you wish to take the value of $_POST["MonthOf"] and subtract 1 month to that. for which i will point you to the strtotime function. and the php date manipulation functions. More precisely,

```
Date('F', strtotime($_POST["MonthOf"] . " last month"));
```

i do suggest you get reading on those though, as simply using stuff without understanding leads to poorly written apps

Comment: So first I need to store this function in a variable like $monthOf = Date('F', strtotime($_POST["MonthOf"] . " last month"));

Comment: that would help the statement's readability, but once again, i strongly encourage you to get familiar with prepared statements, and rewite your statement accordingly! hope it worked out for you!